# kernel thread native thread os thread

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

can any one please tell me. Are all term "kernel thread", "native thread" and "Os thread" represent kernel thread?  Or they are different? If they are different what is relationship among all?

Comment: Yes, they are synonyms.

Answer (score 5):

There's no real standard for that. Terminology varies depending on context. However I'll try to explain the different kind of threads that I know of (and add fibers just for completeness as I've seen people call them threads).

-- **Threading within the kernel**

These are most likely what your *kernel thread* term refers to. They only exist at the kernel level. They allow (a somewhat limited) parallel execution of the kernel code itself.

-- **Application threading**

These are what the term *thread* generally means. They are separate threads of parallel execution which may be scheduled on different processors, that share the same address space and are handled as a single process by the operating system.

The POSIX standard defines the properties threads should have in POSIX compliant systems (in fact the libraries and how each library entry is supposed to behave). Windows threading model is extremely similar to the POSIX one and, AFAIK, it's safe to talk of threading in general the way I did: parallel execution that happens within the same process and can be scheduled on different processors.

-- **Ancient linux threading**

In the early days the linux kernel did not support threading. However it did support creating two different processes that shared the same address space. There was a project (LinuxThreads) that tried to use this to implement some sort of threading abilities.

The problem was, of course, that the kernel would still treat them as separate processes. The result was therefore not POSIX compliant. For example the treatment of signals was problematic (as signals are a process level concept). It was IN THIS VERY SPECIFIC CONTEXT that the term "native" started to become common. It refers to "native" as in "kernel level" support for threading.

With help from the kernel actual support for POSIX compliant threading was finally implemented. Today that's the only kind of threading that really deserves the name. The old way is, in fact, not real threading at all. It's a sharing of the address space by multiple processes, and as such should be referred to. But there was a time when that **was** referred to as threading (as it was the only thing you could do with Linux).

-- **User level and Green threading**

This is another context where "native" is often used to contrast to another threading model. Green threads and userl level threads are threads that do happen within the same process, but they are totally handled at userlevel. Green threads are used in virtual machines (especially those that implement pcode execution, as is the case for the java virtual machine), and they are also implemented at library level by many languages (examples: Haskell, Racket, Smalltalk).

These threads do not need to rely on any threading facilities by the kernel (but often do rely on asynchronous I/O). As such they generally cannot schedule on separate processors. In these contexts "native thread" or "OS thread" could be used to refer to the actual kernel scheduled threads in contrast to the green/user level threads.

Note that "cannot be scheduled on separate processors" is only true if they are used alone. In an hybrid system that has both user level/green threads and native/os threads, it may be possible to create exactly one native/os thread for each processor (and on some systems to set the affinity mask so that each only runs on a specific processor) and then effectively assign the userlevel threads to these.

-- **Fibers and cooperative multitasking**

I have seen some people call these threads. It's improper, the correct name is fibers. They are also a model of parallel execution, but contrary to threads (and processes) they are cooperative. Which means that whenever a fiber is running, the other fibers will not run until the running fiber voluntarily "yields" execution accepting to be suspended and eventually resumed later.

Comment: Java, .Net and Haskell all use native/kernel threading. The GNU Smalltalk implementation uses user level threads, but there are implementations that use kernel threading too.